# Insert space between text and number for cells within column

Tags: vba, excel

I've already written a code that inserts a space between text and numbers, separating 'unspaced' days and months from dates, and it works as it's supposed to.

The only problem is that I'm using an `If then` structure to determine which Regular Expressions `pattern` I should use.

If the first character of the date is a number, then knowing that it is in the '`DayMonth`' sequence, I use this pattern: `"(.*\d)(?! )(\D.*)"`. Otherwise, assuming that it isn't in the `'DayMonth'` sequence but rather in the '`MonthDay`' sequence, I use the other pattern: `"(.*\D)(?! )(\d.*)"`.

**Is there any way to use two patterns at once for the Regular Expressions object to scan through so that I can get rid of the `If Then` structure?**

My code below:

```
Sub SpaceMonthDayIf()

Dim col As Range
Dim i As Long

Set col = Application.InputBox("Select Date Column", "Obtain Object Range", Type:=8)

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, col.Column).End(xlUp).Row

        If IsNumeric(Left(Cells(i, col.Column).Value, 1)) Then
        .Pattern = "(.*\d)(?! )(\D.*)"
        Cells(i, col.Column) = .Replace(Cells(i, col.Column), "$1 $2")

        Else
        .Pattern = "(.*\D)(?! )(\d.*)"
        Cells(i, col.Column) = .Replace(Cells(i, col.Column), "$1 $2")

            End If

                Next

                    End With

End Sub
```

For clarity, here's what happens when I run my code:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a, i As Long

With Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    a = .Value
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(\d+)"
        For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
            a(i, 1) = Application.Trim(.Replace(a(i, 1), " $1 "))
        Next i
    End With
    .Columns(2).Value = a
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Good algorithm.  But why `Application.Trim`?  Why not just use the VBA function `Trim`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Application Trim will remove any extra spaces between strings while just Trim removes extra spaces at the right and left of the strings

Comment: I understand that.  But the original string should not have any unwanted spaces other than at the beginning and the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Ron for pointing that out. It is just in case

Comment: that's a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid that by inserting your space differently.  Here is a `Function` written with early-binding, but you can change that to late-binding.

Match the junction between a letter and a number, then construct a string, inserting a space appropriately.

```
Option Explicit
Function InsertSpace(S As String) As String
    Const sPat As String = "[a-z]\d|\d[a-z]"
    Dim RE As RegExp, MC As MatchCollection

Set RE = New RegExp
With RE
    .Global = False
    .Pattern = sPat
    .IgnoreCase = True
    If .Test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        With MC(0)
            InsertSpace = Left(S, .FirstIndex + 1) & " " & Mid(S, .FirstIndex + 2)
        End With
    End If
End With

End Function
```

You can also accomplish this without using Regular Expressions:

**EDIT** Pattern change for `Like` operator

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Function InsertSpace2(S As String) As String
    Dim I As Long

For I = 1 To Len(S)
    If Mid(S, I, 2) Like "#[a-z]" Or Mid(S, I, 2) Like "[a-z]#" Then
        InsertSpace2 = Left(S, I) & " " & Mid(S, I + 1)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next I

End Function
```

Comment: I'll be honest. If there's a solution that doesn't require Regular Expressions, being unfamiliar with it, I'll take it. Thanks

Comment: Seems like I was a little too optimistic... The function without regular expressions does not work for dates that are: `DayMonth`. It outputs for example: '1 0Jun'

Comment: @Sam Thought I had handled that. Non-regex code edited and should work without a hitch